# Can android delay or suspend my async task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it possible that the android OS may delay or suspend my asynctask for some reason. If so what can I do to ensure that my task (e.g fetching data from database) is not delayed or suspend. Run it on a UI thread maybe but I have read that it is not a good idea as it can freeze the UI and cause lag.

Comment: Under what circumstances it it delaying or suspending your task?

Comment: I am fetching the data from a the database and populating a listview. I fetch the data using a async task and store it in the arraylist once the async task gets completed I call notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute() function to update the listview adapter. Most of the time the list loads fine but sometime there is a delay (I see the blank screen) and after some time the listview gets updated.

Comment: How are you sure that its not just taking longer to fetch from the database then expected? Disk io can be slow.

Comment: Because 99% of the time the query runs fast and I dont see this problem. Plus the number of records in my database is small and sqlite queries are very fast anyway, there must be something else causing the delay.

Comment: Its not delaying but it is some sort of congestion due some part of your app uses also the Asyntask. Asynctask runs on a shared thread, therefore it will execute the first task in the queue then another queu and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that the android OS may delay or suspend my asynctask for some reason.

It might be blocked by another instance of an `AsyncTask`. By default they run on a single background thread: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> If so what can I do to ensure that my task (e.g fetching data from database) is not delayed or suspend.

Investigate what exactly causes the delay. Is it something inside `doInBackground` method or maybe delay happens before or after the background operation. It can be anything, hard to tell without debugging the code.

> Run it on a UI thread maybe but I have read that it is not a good idea as it can freeze the UI and cause lag.

Although `AsyncTask` is not a good solution in this case, it should work fine if you implement it correctly. Other approaches to consider will be `Loader`s, or `AsyncQueryHandler` with `ContentProvider`. Depends on your use case.

Comment: U are not entirely right, AsyncTask uses threadPoolExecutor to run operations, and simple LinkedBlockingQueue to store tasks, with absolute minimum of 2 threads and maximum of twice the number of processors (2*C+1), threads are named with "AsyncTask #" and are not killed after AsyncTask is completed, instead they will wait till next task.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L208

Comment: Thanks for the info. According to your link, there is a line:  private static volatile Executor sDefaultExecutor = SERIAL_EXECUTOR; . `AsyncTask` *can* use a threadPoolExecutor, but the default behavior is serial.

Comment: @Inverce `Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.` Link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            holdWait = false;
            stop = false;
        }

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        synchronized (this) {
            while(true) {
                if(Work) return null;
                if(HaveWork) {
                    //make some
                } else {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mynotify() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if(holdWait) {
                notify();
                holdWait = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setStopWork() {
        synchronized (this) {
            stop= false;
            if(holdWait) {
                notify();
                holdWait = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question. I am not keeping any reference to asynctask and running it again and againg. I just run the asyctask to fetch data from the database only once when my app starts.

Comment: @DayemSiddiqui may this will help you